# Display 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11 as 1-6,8,10-11

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, logic

> I have this sequence **1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11**
>
> Expected output is **1-6,8,10-11**

This problem is about formatting the sequence in easy readable form

I tried with c# and used many if & else.

Interviewer said, there is some simple algorithm to do this.

I have no idea how to achive this very simple.

> Also for 1,2,3 i shown 1-3. They said its wrong!.

Is there any design pattern(interpreter) involved in this logic?

Comment: Did they say why conversion from `1,2,3` to `1-3` is wrong? I cannot see what could be wrong with this case

Comment: I asked them why it is. They said, 'we cant tell the output, go and find' :(

Comment: Do you mean you output `1-3` for the specific example `1,2,3,4,7,9,10`? Or for a different input e.g. `1,2,3,7,9,10`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java display input in range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284372/java-display-input-in-range)

Comment: Isnt the continuity lost at 6 and 8, there is no 7 and 9

Comment: @Rawling, its not a specific example. Its a kind of logic to use a simple format to display a sequence no. They can try with any sequence

Comment: Are you ok with a logic (algorithm)?

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering whether `1-3` was wrong because you were supposed to be outputting `1-4`, or whether it was wrong because they only want 4+ elements in a row to be replaced, not 3 elements in a row.

Comment: @Rawling, I think you may be correct. But 4+ is not mentioned anywhere in the question :(

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Just curious what your reasoning behind rolling back my edit was - was there anything wrong with it?

Comment: @J.Steen: I found the original version way more readable (main reason). Furthermore, removing the Java tag but not the C# tag is arbitrary, because the algorithm is the same for each language.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Fair enough on readability, though I'm of the opinion that quote-markup should be used for quotes, not highlighting. However, the question only mentions c#. If the algorithm is the same in any language (which it largely is) then all language tags should be removed. Yes?

Comment: @J.Steen: Agreed, removing all language tags is valid. About the quoting being (mis-)used as highlighting: I think it's ok, because it makes the question more readable.

Comment: I am wondering from where they taken this puzzle to resolve?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Fair enough. Readability above perceived formatting "correctness". I agree.

Comment: @Rawling: A minimum group length doesn't seem to apply. `10, 11` is displayed as `10-11`...

Comment: try `print("1-6,8,10-11")`

Comment: I love how this question has nine answers with code, and **no answer with an explanation**. (Yes, it’s a pretty straightforward algorithm; but still.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You are free to add one, if you think it is necessary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11 };

        int start, end;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            start = numbers[i];

            while (i < numbers.Length - 1 && numbers[i] + 1 == numbers[i + 1])
                i++;

            end = numbers[i];

            if(start == end)
                Console.WriteLine(start);
            else
                Console.WriteLine(start + " - " + end);
        }
```

This will display subsequent numbers that grow incrementally as range. Numbers that are not increasing linearly are not written as part of a range.

Here is another version of the first approach, it utilizes the same `for` loop to iterate on range:

```
        int temp = numbers[0], start, end;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            start = temp;

            if (i < numbers.Length - 1 )
                // if subsequent numbers are incremental loop further
                if (numbers[i] + 1 == numbers[i + 1])
                    continue;
                // if they are not, number at index i + 1 is a new 'start' for the next iteration
                else
                    temp = numbers[i + 1];

            end = numbers[i];

            if (start == end)
                Console.WriteLine(start);
            else
                Console.WriteLine(start + " - " + end);
        }
```

Comment: This logic seems pretty simple to me :)

Comment: I agree, the logic and implementation are quite simple:)

Comment: @IvanG Can the reverse be possible?

if the user inputs as 10,1-4,5-8, 9 the output should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Answer (score 5):

A simple implementation in C# could look like this:

```
public string Format(IEnumerable<int> input)
{
    var result = string.Empty;

    var previous = -1;
    var start = -1;
    var first = true;

    foreach(var i in input)
    {
        if(start == -1)
            start = i;
        else if(previous + 1 != i)
        {
            result += FormatRange(start, previous, first);
            first = false;
            start = i;
        }

        previous = i;
    }

    if(start != -1)
        result += FormatRange(start, previous, first);

    return result;
}

public string FormatRange(int start, int end, bool isFirst)
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    if(!isFirst)
        result += ", ";
    if(start == end)
        result += start;
    else
        result += string.Format("{0}-{1}", start, end);
    return result;
}
```

This will also output `1-3` for the input `1,2,3`, which is perfectly valid. Without a specification what the output should be instead it's impossible to answer that part.

Comment: Good answer, but I think the point (as least of the interview question) was to find a simple algorithm, not to 'cheat' by using APIs.

Comment: @Dukeling: Identifying the ranges *is* done using a simple algorithm.

Comment: @Dukeling: But I changed it anyway to not use LINQ for the output.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not a suitable answer for an interview question, but using LINQ is another way to solve this.

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11 };
var remains = numbers.AsEnumerable();

while (remains.Any())
{
    int first = remains.First();
    int last = remains.TakeWhile((x, i) => x - first == i).Last();
    remains = remains.Skip(last - first + 1);
    Console.Write(first + (first == last ? "" : "-" + last) + (remains.Any() ? "," : Environment.NewLine));
}
```

Comment: This is the neatest version here.

Comment: Note that this is iterating the source sequence *many* times, which is not suitable for arbitrary enumerables, even if it works fine for an array.

Answer (score 2):

Java code:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11};
int start = arr[0], last = arr[0];
String output = "";

for (int i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++)
{
  if (i == arr.length || arr[i] != last+1)
  {
    if (output.length() != 0)
      output += ",";
    if (start == last)
      output += start;
    else
      output += start + "-" + last;
    if (i != arr.length)
      start = last = arr[i];
  }
  else
     last = arr[i];
}

System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres my best attempt. Not clever, but simple enough to satisfy that requirement I believe. I'm still pretty confused as to why "1-3" was wrong though....

```
    var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12 };

    var groups = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    groups.Add(numbers.First(), numbers.First());

    foreach (var num in numbers.Skip(1))
    {
        var grp = groups.Last();
        if (grp.Value + 1 == num)
        {
            groups[grp.Key] = num;
        }
        else
        {
            groups.Add(num, num);
        }
    }

    var output = string.Join(",", groups.Select(grp => (grp.Key == grp.Value) ? grp.Value.ToString() : grp.Key.ToString() + "-" + grp.Value.ToString()));
```

Note: of course using the dictionary and linq etc is completely unnecessary (and way too specific for an answer requiring an algorithm), but I thought it highlighted the grouping aspect of the problem nicely

Answer (score 2):

The following groups consecutive integers, and outputs a string for each group. However, it also allows you to specify the minimum length of group which you want to hyphenate; anything less will just give you the individual numbers. Thus if you only want to hyphenate groups of 4 or more, you can pass in 4; if you want to hyphenate pairs, you can pass in 2. (I'd want to use 3 myself, but I can't tell what *they* want.)

It also doesn't keep any collections of numbers as it goes along, because you don't need to.

Method:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Group(IEnumerable<int> input, int minLength)
{
    int currentStart = int.MinValue;
    int currentLength = 0;
    foreach (int c in input)
    {
        if (currentLength > 0)
            if (currentStart + currentLength == c)
                currentLength++;
            else
            {
                if (currentLength >= minLength)
                    yield return string.Format("{0}-{1}",
                        currentStart, currentStart + currentLength - 1);
                else
                    for (int i = currentStart; i < currentStart + currentLength; i++)
                        yield return i.ToString();
                currentStart = c;
                currentLength = 1;
            }
        else
        {
            currentStart = c;
            currentLength = 1;
        }
    }
    if (currentLength >= minLength)
        yield return string.Format("{0}-{1}",
            currentStart, currentStart + currentLength + 1);
    else
        for (int i = currentStart; i < currentStart + currentLength; i++)
            yield return i.ToString();
}
```

Usage:

```
int minCount = 3;
int[] input = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11 };
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", Group(input, minCount)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is no valid C# code but to show the Idea.

Sort the list from Min to Max then do this:

```
For i = Min to Max
{
  if i < MaxFound
    continue;

  int step = 1;
  Output = i;
  while Found(i + Step)
  {
     Step++;
     MaxFound = i + Step;
  }
  if i < MaxFound 
    Output = (i + "-" + MaxFound);

  Output += ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12);
}

public static void print(int ... nums) {
    System.out.print(nums[0]);
    int idx = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++, idx++) {
        if(nums[i] - nums[i - 1] != 1) {
            if(idx > 1) {
                System.out.print(" - " + nums[i - 1]);
            }
            System.out.print(", " + nums[i]);
            idx = 0;
        }
    }

    if(idx > 1)
        System.out.println(" - " + nums[nums.length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: I dont see the first number in the format. It shows -5 instead of 1-5

Comment: @BadDeveloper First line of code prints first element. May be you missed it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Haskell version:

```
import Data.List

parseRange [] = ""
parseRange n = 
  let range = takeWhile (\x -> isInfixOf [x,x+1] n) n
  in if not (null range)
        then show (head range) ++ "-" ++ show (last range + 1) 
             ++ (if length (tail n) > 1 then "," else "") 
             ++ parseRange (drop (length range + 1) n) 
        else show (head n) ++ (if null (tail n) then "" else ",") 
             ++ parseRange (drop 1 n)
```

Output:

```
*Main> parseRange [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11]
"1-6,8,10-11"
```

Answer (score 0):

And a way to do it with fold in F# - just for fun.

```
let parseRange numbers = 
  numbers 
  |> Seq.fold 
    (fun list n -> 
      match list with
      |(a,b) :: tail when b+1 = n -> (a, n) :: tail
      |_ -> (n,n) :: list) []
  |> List.rev 
  |> Seq.map (fun (a,b) -> if a = b then sprintf "%i" a else sprintf "%i-%i" a b)
  |> String.concat ","
```